# Get sprite prefab width

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I have a **Prefab** which is basically a sprite. 
It has a **javascript attached** & I want to get width of it.

Here is what my assumption is-

```
private var getObjectWidth:float;

function start(){
    // want to get the gameObject's spriteRenderer 
    var gameObjectRenderer = transform.gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer);

    // then get the width from Sprite bounds
    getObjectWidth = gameObjectRenderer.sprite.bounds.size.x;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html

check that link out. There is no sprite variable for Renderer

I think you could use

```
gameObjectRenderer.bounds.max.x - gameObjectRenderer.bounds.min.x;
```

or more simply

```
gameObjectRenderer.bounds.extents;
```

check this to

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Let me check, in details.